# Equivalent for ANYDATA datatype in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle

While migrating oracle to Postgres, we have datatype ANYDATA.

Is there any equivalent in postgres for ANYDATA

Comment: Is that a column defined as anydata or do you use this type in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has not type like this type. Theoretically it should not be hard to implement this type in extension, but I don't know about some implementation.

Today almost all values can be effectively encoded to `jsonb` data type. But there are not exact information about original datatype. But I think so it can work.

```
(2023-01-24 06:23:21) postgres=# select to_jsonb(1);
┌──────────┐
│ to_jsonb │
╞══════════╡
│ 1        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

(2023-01-24 06:24:34) postgres=# select to_jsonb(row(10,20,30));
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│            to_jsonb            │
╞════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"f1": 10, "f2": 20, "f3": 30} │
└────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

(2023-01-24 06:24:46) postgres=# select to_jsonb(current_date);
┌──────────────┐
│   to_jsonb   │
╞══════════════╡
│ "2023-01-24" │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```